# Nested lua_CFunction calls

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

What is the best way to deal with nested lua_CFunction calls? Assume I have two function like this:

```
static int function2(lua_State *L) {
   int i = luaL_checkint(L, 1);

   /* do something */

   return 1;
};

static int function1(lua_State *L) {
   struct udata *u = luaL_checkudata(L, 1, UDATA_METATABLE);
   int i = luaL_checkint(L, 2);

   /* do something */

   /* this does not work, first on call stack is udata, not int */
   return function2(L);
};
```

The function call as above does not work.  One option is to modify `function2()` to use the last element (index -1) on stack, but this is not a sollution in general since `function2()` might be called from various places with different call stacks.
Another way would be to replace the `return function2(L);` by

```
lua_pushcfunction(L, function2);
lua_pushvalue(L, 2);
lua_call(L, 1, 1);  /* need to know number of results */
```

I assume this gives `function2()` its own call stack so there is no need to modify it.  But this sollution seems overly complicated for functions with more parameters since it requires duplicating all of them on the stack.

**tl;dr:** What is the recommended way/a good way to call a `lua_CFunction` from inside another one?

Answer (score 3):

In `function1` you are expecting the bottom of the stack to be user data.
When you call `function2` directly, the LuaState has not changed and therefore the bottom is still user data.

You can successfully call `function2` from `function1` by ensuring an integer is at index 1.

You could do this by calling `lua_insert(L, 1)` which will move the top (assuming index 2), to index 1.

You could also do this by popping all values the pushing the integer back on:

```
lua_pop(L, lua_gettop(L));
lua_pushnumber(L, i);
return function2(L);
```

Answer (score 1):

lua_CFunction is not fully Lua function. It just a way to create Lua function/closure.

```
static int function1(lua_State *L) {
    ....
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_pushcfunction(L, function2);
    lua_pushvalue(L, 2);
    lua_call(L, 1, LUA_MULTRET);
    return lua_gettop(L) - 1;
}
```

The Lua equivalent is

```
function function1(arg)
  return (function(arg) --[[body of f2]] end)(arg)
end
```

So you create each time new function and call it.
For C function it is quite ok because it no need to compile and you do not need upvalue.
Also Lua 5.2 introduce light function for that.
But if you want equivalent for

```
int i = 1
local function function2(arg)
  i = i + 1
  ...
end

function function1(arg)
  return function2(arg)
end
```

You need a way to find real Lua function e.g. (not tested)

```
int f2_ref;

static int function1(lua_State *L) {

  ...

  -- push `function2` on stack
  lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, f2_ref);

  -- as above
}

static int function2(lua_State *L) {
  int my_upvalue = lua_tonumber(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
  my_upvalue++;
  lua_pushnumber(L, my_upvalue);
  lua_replace(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));


  ...
}

int luaopen_foo(lua_State *L){
  -- Here we create instance of Lua function(closure)
  lua_pushnumber(L, 1);
  lua_pushcclosure(L, function2, 1);
  f2_ref = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

  lua_pushcclosure(L, function1, 0);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I am not sure I understand completely, yet, but will have a look at the manual for the closure functions and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that calling it through lua *is* the recommended way to do that but if you don't want to do that for some reason then Timma's suggestions are the right ones.